# Constrained global optimization question

Tags: optimization, constraint

Given an example:

Employee A,B,C can work on three tasks 1,2,3. 
The value created by each employee on each task are:
A:(9,10,11) 
B:(4,5 ,10)
C:(1,3 ,5)
Ideally, A,B,C all work on task 3 will create the highest value.

But there is a constraint that each task can only be worked on by one person.

So the best solution will be A1, B3, C2 with total value of 9 + 10 + 3.

Is there any optimization algorithm can do solve problem like this if I have more people, more tasks and not only one but several people can work on one task together?

Thanks to forecaster, problem solved by using excel solver.
I am trying to replicate this in R now:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225830/how-to-replicate-excel-solver-in-r

Comment: Yes, fairly straight forward, you could use excel spreadsheet solver  to solve an optimization problem like this.

Comment: Thanks forecaster, it worked! I am trying to replicate this in R. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: To be honest, excel solver is much more easy to use due to user interface and it also has evolutionary algorithm to solve integer optimization such as yours, I rarely use R for optimization. You could try optim function and there are few evolutionaly algorithms such as GA/simulated annealing etc,.

Comment: Long time ago I used to be industrial/mechanical engineer, I used to use a software called [lindo](http://www.lindo.com/) optimization system for scheduling/linear programming/integer programming. you could give it a try.

Comment: Thanks forecaster! I found the excel solver is truly convenient as well. However, the other part of my code to generate values are in R, so I'd like to integrate them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication in R is answered at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225830/how-to-replicate-excel-solver-in-r